# All-time-high not plotting correctly in Pine Script

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to create a script which shows the all-time-high of a given symbol as a horizontal line on Trading View. I have worked out how to search for the all-time-high but when I try to display it, it seems to display a previous all-time-high. I've added diagnostic output, which seems to show the price I would expect the line to be drawn, but on the actual chart it draws it lower. What am I doing wrong?

```
// © dickymoore

//@version=4
study("All-time-high", overlay=true)

// input
Athlw = input(title="All-time-high line widths", type=input.integer, defval=4, minval=0, maxval=4)
Athlc = input(title="All-time-high line color", type=input.color, defval=color.new(color.fuchsia,50))
years = input(title="Years back to search for an ATH", type=input.integer, defval=6,minval=0, maxval=100)


seriesForAth=security(syminfo.tickerid,"M",high,barmerge.gaps_off,barmerge.lookahead_off)
highestHigh = highest(seriesForAth,(12*years))


// Draw lines from the previous highs and lows
newSession = change(time('D'))
count = barssince(newSession)

var line AllTimeHigh = na

if (newSession)
    AllTimeHigh  := line.new(x1=bar_index[1],y1=highestHigh,
                 x2=bar_index,y2=highestHigh, extend=extend.both, color=Athlc,width=Athlw)
    
    line.delete(id = AllTimeHigh[1]) 
         
         
//diagnostics

f_print(_text) =>
    var _label = label.new(bar_index, na, _text, xloc.bar_index, yloc.price, color(na), label.style_none, color.gray, size.large, text.align_left)
    label.set_xy(_label, bar_index, highest(10)[1])
    label.set_text(_label, _text)
f_print("Diagnostics \n" + "\nHigh = " + tostring(highestHigh))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easier and more compact.

```
//@version=4
study("All-time-high", "ATH", overlay=true)

// input
Athlw = input(title="All-time-high line widths", type=input.integer, defval=4, minval=0, maxval=4)
Athlc = input(title="All-time-high line color", type=input.color, defval=color.new(color.fuchsia,50))
years = input(title="Years back to search for an ATH", type=input.integer, defval=6,minval=0, maxval=100)

var float   highestHigh = 0
var line    allTimeHigh = line.new(na, na, na, na, extend=extend.both, color=Athlc, width=Athlw)

if high > highestHigh
    highestHigh := high

line.set_xy1(allTimeHigh, bar_index-1, highestHigh)
line.set_xy2(allTimeHigh, bar_index,   highestHigh)
```

**Edit 1**
Come to think of it, we don't need to move the line at every bar.
We can just move the line on the last bar.

```
//@version=4
study("All-time-high", "ATH", overlay=true)

// input
Athlw = input(title="All-time-high line widths", type=input.integer, defval=4, minval=0, maxval=4)
Athlc = input(title="All-time-high line color", type=input.color, defval=color.new(color.fuchsia,50))
years = input(title="Years back to search for an ATH", type=input.integer, defval=6,minval=0, maxval=100)

var float   highestHigh = 0
var line    allTimeHigh = line.new(na, na, na, na, extend=extend.both, color=Athlc, width=Athlw)

if high > highestHigh
    highestHigh := high

if barstate.islast
    line.set_xy1(allTimeHigh, bar_index-1, highestHigh)
    line.set_xy2(allTimeHigh, bar_index,   highestHigh)
```

Comment: Such a quick response and nicely written script. Thanks so much!

Comment: Added Edit 1 to my answer.